# How can i get the right value?

Tags: javascript

I met a issue about number calculation in JavaScript, the scenario is listed as

below.

```
var number = 572.055
var result = Math.round(572.055*100)/100
```

I would like to get result `572.06`, but the result is `572.05`, i try that 
`alert(572.055*100)`, it alert the value `57205.4999999999`,i don't know 
the reason. could you help to tell me
how to avoid this issue? thanks a lot!

Comment: Related: [Round to at most 2 decimal places in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript)

Comment: This works fine https://jsfiddle.net/m6z8th0y/1/

Comment: I add '0.00001' to number,it don't impact the normal case and can also resolve the exception case.                                                               
var result = Math.round((number+0.00001)*100)/100 .

Answer (score -1):

You could use Math.ceil() instead of Math.round.